# Table of contents Word wont retain formatting

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to set up a table of contents that has specific styles i.e numbers before, no lines, etc etc using the custom table of contents tab.

I can get this set up but everytime I update the table, it switches to the ugly default look.

I am trying to set up a master document for a client and I need to fix this. I cant set any styles for tables that I could click after updating to revert it back.

Any help would be great as to the best way of setting this up, I have been at it for days.

Comment: Did you modify the TOC styles?

Comment: I mean in the create a table options, where you choose things like the tab leader and set it up just how you like. Some of which does not seem to be part of the TOC styles?

Comment: Set the leader options on the Paragraph dialog _after_ using the MultiLevel List dialog to setup the indent and tab options.